# How to stop aperture indicator from flashing when in shutter priority mode with manual ISO on Sony a6000?

Tags: aperture, manual-mode, sony-alpha, shutter-priority

When shooting in Shutter mode I can't get the aperture indicator on the screen to stop flashing when I set an ISO value.

I'm using a Sigma 60mm F2.8 fixed lens.

I've tried taking a shot in Intelligent Mode then replicating the values in Shutter mode but the aperture indicator still flashes even if I increase/decrease the shutter speed.

The problem doesn't occur if I set ISO to Auto but I want to avoid this when shooting in low light....

Comment: What are you setting the ISO value to? The same one selected automatically?

Comment: Yes. In a stable lighting environment I replicate the auto values in shutter mode and the aperture indicator keeps flashing. If I then set the ISO to auto it auto selects the same ISO value and the aperture indicator doesn't flash.....Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Have you looked in the manual to confirm the reason for the aperture indicator to flash? Has there ever been a time that you've used the camera in shutter priority mode when the aperture indicator did *not* flash? Perhaps this is normal behavior for this camera?

Comment: The manual states the aperture and Shutters speed indicators and will flash if the camera "thinks" the values you've selected aren't going to give you the right exposure. However as above if I set the ISO to auto in Shutter mode the flashing will stop but start again if I move from Auto and set the ISO manually on the value the camera had auto selected...I've experimented with increasing/decreasing the ISO manually but the flashing is always there....I'm beginning to think this may be normal behaviour for the camera...thanks for your response

Comment: With what specific ISO values, apertures, and shutter times is this occurring?

Comment: 1/100 f4.5 iso 125 for example but its across all shutter speeds, apertures and ISOs when I attempt to replicate the values shown in the same situation using Intelligent Mode.....In shutter mode I can adjust all the settings to match intelligent mode and they don't flash but as soon as I half depress the shutter release the aperture indicator flashes....when I take the shot the exposure is as I wanted it....

Comment: Thanks for your help with this one. To keep things simpler lets keep the conversation in your initial response rather than duplicating

Comment: @GordonNeech Can you provide a link to the manual page that states that the indicators flash, please? When I asked Sony about this they couldn't understand the question and thought I was talking about using a flash gun! I could find nothing in the manual about this when I got my A6000. There are lots of "Gotchas" with the A6000, and note that the Sigma 2.8 lenses are not fully compatible with this camera.

Comment: @Neil P Item 25 Shutter Priority, First Item under Note.Its say something similar under Item 26 Aperture Priority and again under Item 27 Manual Priority.....To date (the last year or so) the Sigma 60mm 2.8 lens has been brilliant in all respects....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have enough light for proper exposure at the lens' maximum aperture and the selected shutter time and ISO, with most cameras the aperture indicator will flash to tell you the image will be underexposed.

Some cameras will also flash one of the exposure parameters if it thinks you've selected less than optimal exposure parameters. One example would be a camera that causes a selected shutter time of 1/15 second when using an 85mm lens - the camera is warning you that the shutter time might be too slow for that lens.

Your Sony camera may be warning you that the aperture value may be less than optimal for whatever reason. Are you using an exceptionally narrow aperture that might lead to diffraction? Are you using a very wide aperture setting that might lead to focusing issues with regard to the narrow depth of field being placed in the intended spot?

> 1/100 f4.5 iso 125 for example but its across all shutter speeds, apertures and ISOs when I attempt to replicate the values shown in the same situation using Intelligent Mode.....In shutter mode I can adjust all the settings to match intelligent mode and they don't flash but as soon as I half depress the shutter release the aperture indicator flashes....when I take the shot the exposure is as I wanted it....

What happens if you move the camera to point at a brighter or darker area than when you initially half pressed the shutter? Does the meter reading change, or stay in the same spot?

> In Intelligent Mode the values keep changing if I move the camera with the shutter half depressed until I take the shot. In Shutter Mode with Shutter and ISO set the Aperture starts to flash when I half depress the shutter and does not change if I move the camera to a brighter or darker object.
>
> Just took a shot in Shutter mode after half depressing the shutter then moving to a brighter object. The metering appears to have locked once I half depress the shutter. In Aperture Mode if I lock the aperture and ISO the metering is continuous...

Some cameras with certain settings applied lock in exposure upon completion of metering and hold it as long as the half press is held. Other settings (even with the same camera) will not lock in metering but will change it as the camera is pointed at areas of differing brightness. **Your camera seems to be notifying you that exposure is locked, rather than continuous.**

Comment: Understood. My issue is the aperture indicator flashes whenever I set the ISO to a fixed value. It stops flashing when I set the ISO to auto even if the ISO value it automatically selects is the same as the value that I'd fixed it at. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Is the resulting exposure in line with what you'd expect in auto mode? (Like, average "correct" exposure?)

Comment: @GordonNeech Have you checked the EXIF data of the images produced to confirm that the ISO displayed by the camera before the shot is taken is the same ISO *actually used* when the camera records the photo? There have been cases of some cameras which, at times, will "shift" the ISO much higher in 'Auto ISO' than the value displayed in the viewfinder or on the rear screen.

Comment: Checked this out and found the exif info matched the screen reading for auto ISO when I took the shot...

Comment: What about the aperture and shutter time? Is the camera "shifting wither one of those when in 'Auto ISO'? Perhaps because ISO is already at your selected maximum ISO value? The more details about the specific exposure settings (and lens used), the more we might be able to help you.

Comment: 1/100 f4.5 iso 125 for example but its across all shutter speeds, apertures and ISOs when I attempt to replicate the values shown in the same situation using Intelligent Mode.....In shutter mode I can adjust all the settings to match intelligent mode and they don't flash but as soon as I half depress the shutter release the aperture indicator flashes....when I take the shot the exposure is as I wanted it....

Comment: What happens if you move the camera to point at a brighter or darker area than when you initially half pressed the shutter? Does the meter reading change, or stay in the same spot? Some cameras with certain settings applied lock in exposure upon completion of metering and hold it as long as the half press is held. Other settings (even with the same camera) will not lock in metering but will change it as the camera is pointed at areas of differing brightness. Your camera may be trying to notify you that exposure is locked, rather than continuous.

Comment: What metering mode are you using (spot, partial, center weighted, matrix/evaluative/whatever Sony calls it)? Does exposure/metering lock when the shutter is half pressed? Or does it continue to update until you take the picture?

Comment: In Intelligent Mode the values keep changing if I move the camera with the shutter half depressed until I take the shot. In Shutter Mode with Shutter and ISO set the Aperture starts to flash when I half depress the shutter and does not change if I move the camera to a brighter or darker object. There are 3 metering modes: Multi, Centre and Spot. Changing this does not alter the behaviour we're looking at. Metering is continuous.

Comment: Just took a shot in Shutter mode after half depressing the shutter then moving to a brighter object. The metering appears to have locked once I half depress the shutter. Ii Aperture Mode if I lock the aperture and ISO  the metering is continuous SO it appears that its a warning in Shutter Mode that the Aperture is locked once I half depress the shutter...

Comment: @GordonNeech There you go.